# Two column responsive css layout

Tags: css, wordpress

Im trying to convert my default category posts to a specific style as show in the image. I'm stuck at the css end and can't figure out a way. Can anyone guide me onto building this kind of layout css?[image]

Comment: Did you inspect the source code of the website your showing?

Comment: By "responsive" do you mean it should look different on mobile devices? (For example, the pictures and captions could stack up into a single-column layout.)

Comment: @YoramdeLangen I have inspected the website css but its conflicting with my existing wordpress theme css. I just want to style like it and not copy their site's css.

Comment: @jkdev Yes when the screen resizes they should stack up in a single column layout.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: You can use bootstrap css for responsive layout, Its best suite for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using w3.css 12 column responsive grid to do this. You can specify grid space for phones tablets and computers.
    [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_grid.asp).
[My code...](https://goo.gl/ubFwXy)

Comment: Make sure you import the css. Here is code that works. Try to resize the result window - https://goo.gl/nOZWs8

Comment: I tried but not the same result as in the original image posted in the question: https://jsfiddle.net/rax7oL1g/

Comment: Try copying the HTML and CSS onto your own page and resize the screen. You can see the effect of resizing it.

Comment: let me try and get back again... :-)